# any smart way to convert nodejs object to a string

Tags: node.js

The problem is coming from this discussion 
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11036#issuecomment-357334325

Terraform doesn't really understand multiple list, so I have to convert it to below format

```
locals {
  test = [{
    a = "a1"
    b = "b1"
  },{
    a= "a2"
    b = "b2"
  }]
}
```

So suppose I have below object

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "value": "foo"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "value": "bar"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "value": "boo"
  },
  {
    "name": "d",
    "value": "far"
  }
]
```

I'd like to convert to **string** as below:

```
[ { name = "a", value = "foo" }, { name = "b", value = "bar" }, { name = "c", value = "boo" }, { name = "d", value = "far" } ]
```

The code I am currently working is to go through each key and export it with new format.

```
$ cat a.js
var array1 = [{"name":"a","value":"foo"},{"name":"b","value":"bar"},{"name":"c","value":"boo"},{"name":"d","value":"far"}]

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  Object.keys(element).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(element[key]);
  });
});

$ node a.js
name
a
value
foo
name
b
value
bar
name
c
value
boo
name
d
value
far
```

Any smart way to convert it, more than go through each key and export the key and value with nominated format?

Comment: @certainPerformance Please don't close it too quick (less than 2 minutes again. Seems you are on Stackoverflow as full time job :-)), you need give the time that I can update my question. By the way, I have fully updated it, can you give any suggestions?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close/98026 - we are all encouraged to close the close-worthy questions immediately. (you have all the time in the world *before* you post a question to do your best to make it presentable, after all)

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex replacing will do the job:

```
var array1 = [{"name":"a","value":"foo"},{"name":"b","value":"bar"},{"name":"c","value":"boo"},{"name":"d","value":"far"}]

a = JSON.stringify(array1);
a = a.replace(/\[|{|\]|}|"/g, "")
a = a.replace(/:|,/g, "\n");

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems your solution is using RegEx to replace more than my way to export the key/value with expected format, let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updates

Finally I go with @MrfksIV 's solution.

The limit is, there should be no space in any values.

```
var array1 = [{"name":"a","value":"foo"},{"name":"b","value":"bar"},{"name":"c","value":"boo"},{"name":"d","value":"far"}]

a = JSON.stringify(array1);
a = a.replace(/"/g, "")
a = a.replace(/:/g, "=")

console.log(a);
```

output is

```
 [{name=a,value=foo},{name=b,value=bar},{name=c,value=boo},{name=d,value=far}]
```